# Power series $e^{-x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, exponential-function

How would I create a power series of $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ around $x_0=1$ without using a Taylor series?

I need to know this for my upcoming exam so I would be really grateful to anyone who could show me how it's done.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you allowed to use?

Comment: I am allowed to use arithmetic and the series representations for basic functions (exp(x), sin(x), cos(x)) as well as the geometric/harmonic series.

Comment: I could maybe try to substitute $x-1$ into $e^{-x^2}$ which will give me $e^{-(x-1)^2-2x+1}$ but I really don't know how to go on from here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not sure if that helps me. I calculated the first few terms and they differ from what wolfram/mathematica puts out. I should be getting:

$1/e-{2(x-1)}/{e}+{(x-1)^2}/{e}$

Comment: Ah, now I see. However, I have no idea how you arrived at that series. Also, if I look at k=1, shouldn't the binomial coefficient be just n? why is it 2n?

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped a lot! Just out of curiosity, what are you studying and what year are you in? (if thats not too personal)

Comment: No problem,I'm actually 2nd year of high school,but I feel like the things I'm doing there is just too easy so I decided to research on my own :).I'll delete my comments and post this as an answer(so that the comment section is not overflowed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$e^{-x^2}=e^{-(x-1+1)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(x-1+1)^{2n}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty{2n\choose k}(x-1)^k}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n{2n\choose 0}}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n{2n\choose 1}(x-1)}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n{2n\choose 2}(x-1)^2}{n!}+\cdots$$

Comment: I am really sorry for accepting this so late but I somehow missed your answer. Thankyou very much.